# Bypass htaccess file restriction

Tags: php, apache, shell, .htaccess, exploit

So, I was trying to upload **PHP** files into **Apache** server, and whenever I browse the file I get **403** error due to htaccess limitations. It turns out that the server only accepts certain files such as "gif|jpg|png|mp4" and other image files.

Is there any way to bypass this?

**NOTE **: I tried the old ways,**PHP**, **Phtml** .. it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to bypass this?

Not unless you edit the .htaccess file or find a vulnerability in Apache.

Note that simply uploading a PHP file doesn't mean the server can execute it. The server needs to have the right software installed and Apache needs to be configured to handle PHP files. You can't just drop a PHP file in there and expect it to work, regardless of what the .htaccess file says.